# How do you print certain number in an array?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to print the corresponding numbers in a diagonal line, but I can only print the numbers going straight down. It prints out 2, 1, 7, 0, 5. But the output doesn't print out in a diagonal. Can someone please help me?

```
public class Main_diagonal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int array1[][] = {
                {2,3,1,5,0 },
                {7,1,5,3,1 },
                {2,5,7,8,1 },
                {0,1,5,0,1 },
                {3,4,9,1,5 }
        };



        for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
        {

            for (int j=0; j<=i;j++)
            {   
                if(i==j){

                    System.out.println(array1[i][j]);
                }

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Also please provide the actual output and the expected output.  It seems you are printing the actual diagonals already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "printing number in a diagonal line" you mean that you need to have the output appear diagonally like this:

```
2
 1
  7
   0
    5
```

Then just have your inner loop print spaces for the times it doesn't print the number.

```
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<=i;j++)
        {   
            if(i==j) { //then print the number and a new line
                System.out.println(array1[i][j]);
            }
            else {
                System.out.print(" "); //pads the line with spaces otherwise
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure which language you're using, so this might not work for you in the current state, but you get the idea.

Once you reveal which language you're using, we can optimise :)

```
String whitespace = "";

for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
  System.out.println(whitespace + array1[i][i]);
  whitespace += " ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code like this:

```
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<=i;j++)
        {   
            if(i==j){
                System.out.println(array1[i][j]);
                break;
            }
            System.out.print(" ");              
        }
    }
```